# Is it safe to name the local variables by ending with "$"?

Tags: scoping

In many cases I need to copy the `` Global` `` symbols `foo` into `Module/Block`, and to memory the meanings of the copies I named them as `fooTemp` before. For example,

```
f[foo_]:=Module[{fooTemp},
  fooTemp=foo;
  foo...
  fooTemp...
]
```

My question is that is it safe to name `fooTemp` as `foo$`? `ref/message/Module/dups` says "It is recommended that names of this form be avoided."

I tried the simple cases like

```
x = 1;
f := Print["value of x: ", x];

Module[{x$},
 {x, x$} // Print;
 ]
(*{1,x$40193}*)

Module[{x, x$},
 {x, x$} // Print;
 ]
(*Module::dups: Conflicting local variables x and x$ found in local variable specification {x,x$}.*)

Block[{x, x$},
 {x, x$} // Print;
 f
 ]; f
(*
{x,x$}
value of x: x
value of x: 1
*)
```

and these are expected from the scopings of `Module/Block`.

Are there other subtlties besides `Module::dups` if naming local variables ending with "$", say nested scoping constructs?

---

It seems that `foo$$` is a better choice?

```
Module[{x, x$$},
 {x, x$$} // Print;
 ]
(*{x$48058,x$$$48058}*)

Module[{x$, x$$},
 {x$, x$$} // Print;
 ]
(*{x$48060,x$$$48060}*)
```

Interestingly `Module[{x$$, x$$$},]` will report `Module::dups` once again.

Comment: I know this isn't safe: `func[s_] := Module[{foo}, foo = s];
func[foo$]` because `Module[{foo},...]` renames`foo` to `foo$`; execute `func[foo$] // Trace` — `foo$$` is probably not a good choice, either. That's the renaming convention used by `DynamicModule[{foo},...]`, which may be renamed again by the Front End. If you know what you're doing, you can possibly get away with it.

Comment: Another comment is that this "need" arising "in many cases" seems strange to me. There are common use-cases like `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},...]` in which global parameters are temporarily reset, but one doesn't need to put a `$` at the end. You could put a non-ASCII character at the end, like ¢ (option-4 on my Mac) or § (option-6), if you want to keep a simple renaming convention.

Comment: "is it safe?" - I'm puzzled by your question: the system specifically gives you a warning and recommends against it! I'd stay away from it, out of an abundance of caution if nothing else...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the examples! I have customized option+xx to other usages. Now I use $$foo as local variables.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, I agree. But for myself these questions are exercises to get better understanding of low-level things.

Comment: @MichaelE2 One situation is using With injecting values, and I don't want to name the local varaibles just randomly.